# How to get MathJax's HTML output just like Stackedit.io?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mathjax

I know I can use

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "displayArea"]);
```

to process. But I don't know how to get the output HTML (I want to save the output in a variable in Javascript).

Moreover, I want this HTML is independent to MathJax's stylesheets. By independent, I mean like HTML output of [stackedit.io](https://stackedit.io/). The output of stackedit is self-containt. It don't need any other CSS or JS.

Please give me some help on this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output of Stackedit is not exactly self-contained.  It [says](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/blob/master/public/res/WELCOME.md#mathjax) "Make sure you include MathJax into your publications to render mathematical expression correctly."

- Doing "Save as HTML" does not load MJ and contains the **browser-specific** mathjax rendering.  E.g. I saved with Chrome => looks fine in Chrome but a mess in FF: ╬У(n)=(nтИТ1)!
- Doing "Save using template" does load MathJax.js and works fine (it still includes browser-specific rendering, but MJ finds the `<script type="math/tex" ...` tags with original math and re-renders).

See [MathJax Output Formats](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output.html) about portability.
Unfortunately there is **no single solution that works well in all browsers**.  I think your best bet is SVG output ([IE9+](http://caniuse.com/svg); size relative to text may be off).

- https://github.com/agrbin/svgtex (and its forks) automate server-side SVG generation.  After grabbing the output (`getElementsByTagName("svg")`) it does some [less trivial stuff](https://github.com/agrbin/svgtex/blob/1dc266b26f9d4f83b7ed4e459bda1c7df2e4136c/engine.js#L52-L78) to produce a self-contained SVG; same would be needed if doing it client-side.

I also wonder if HTML-CSS output can become more portable on a page using a thorough CSS reset.  I haven't read anybody investigating it — though I guess if it were *that* easy, the MathJax devs would have done it long ago...

Another deal-breaker with HTML-CSS is fonts.  If you really can't load external resources, you must embed them as base64 data: URLs.  The full fonts are too heavy, so you'll want to subset fonts on the fly — scary...  (With SVG output embedding glyphs is much easier, as I linked above svgtex does it in 25 lines and gives you a single SVG image.)

Comment: Thank you! So the most trivial solution is to include MathJax's js/css? And another solution is to use SVG, right?

Comment: For viewing online you just add the script tag (pointing to stackedit.io or mathjax CDN), it will load whatever parts of MathJax needed.  But it's not really self-contained, doesn't work offline.  Bundling ALL of mathjax in one file is impractical (39MB without image fonts).  SVG + script tag may be best compromise — but please expain what exactly do you mean by "indepentent output" (and why do you need that).

Comment: Your explanation is exactly what I want, thanks :) I want the output be self-contained because I want to use something like "Web View" to display the output on mobile app.

Comment: Aaah, you should have said that in the question, would get better answers (actually, maybe edit it now?).  Then you can bundle MathJax as part of the mobile app without inflating each document.  Also, it means you know which browser it is.  [Search the user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mathjax-users/mobile$20app) for discussions...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple. Just use

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "displayArea"]);
```

and then use jQuery

```
var text = $("#displayArea").html();
```

Done!